# Add country suffix to domain with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a site with URLs like:

```
www.domain.com/pagea
www.domain.com/pageb
www.domain.com/whatever
```

I would like them to be redirect to:

```
www.domain.com.br/pagea
www.domain.com.br/pageb
www.domain.com.br/whatever
```

How can I do this with .htaccess?

Being that, I want to redirect all non .br pages to .br pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this code in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled and htaccess allowed

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I was not very clear in my question and I've edited it, can you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Try this too

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.domain.com.br/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

or try this with (RedirectMatch)

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/?$ http://www.domain.com.br/$1
```